# SQL data insertion to a column error

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, sql-insert

I created following table in SQL. then entered data. Then I added another column (email). Next I need to insert data to email column. But there is an error.

```
CREATE TABLE Library_books (
    ISBN VARCHAR(15),
    Book_name VARCHAR(20),
    subject TEXT(12),
    student_id VARCHAR(4),
    borrow_date DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (ISBN),
    FOREIGN KEY (student_id)
    REFERENCES student (SID)
);


INSERT INTO Library_books VALUES  ('1-22-5567-4'    ,'Vectors'            ,'Mathematics', 'S021', '2015-04-23'),
                              ('978-14840-0'    ,'The C Programming ' ,'Computer'   , 'S005', '2016-03-01'),
                              ('567-2-13-145-3' ,'Code complete'      ,'Computer'   , 'S005', '2016-06-04'),
                              ('345-6-7889-5'   ,'How to solve it'    ,'Mathematics', 'S090', '2016-08-12'),
                              ('34-22-34556-4'  ,'Real Analysis'      ,'Mathematics', 'S021', '2016-10-22'),
                              ('3-445-7-8'      ,'Python'             ,'Computer'   , 'S021', '2016-09-11');



INSERT INTO student (email) VALUES   ('Bob@gmail.com'),
                                 ('John@gmail.com'),
                                 ('Albert@gmail.com'), 
                                 ('Sam@gmail.com'), 
                                 ('Tom@gmail.com'),
                                 ('Liz@gmail.com') ;

CREATE table student (SID varchar(4) NOT NULL,
                  student_name varchar(10) NOT NULL,
                  address varchar(12) NOT NULL,
                  age int NOT NULL,
                  telephoneNo varchar(12) NOT NULL,
                  primary key (SID));
```

Results in:

> ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I think you should not use the ISBN as primary key. It stays in the database and when you try to insert the same data, this error will occur.

Comment: @SureshPrajapati "ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'"

Comment: Can you please include the schema for the Student table, it seems the error relates to the insertion of the emails. It's not very clear which statement the error relates to.

Comment: @deHaar Thanks !, Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: @Andrew  I edied my Question Could you have a look ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using "SQL Server version: 5.5.27 MySQL Community Server (GPL)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO student VALUES (S01, 'name',...)
```

is used to insert full set of values(complete row) to a table after creating it.

But to enter data to a new column created by using the **ALTER TABLE** statement
you have to use the **UPDATE**,

```
UPDATE student
SET email = 'bob@gmail.com'
WHERE SID = 'S01';
```

To update multiple rows with distinct(differant) data values you need to use the UPDATE statement multiple times as follows,

```
UPDATE student SET email = 'Bob@gmail.com' WHERE SID = 1;
UPDATE student SET email = 'John@gmail.com' WHERE SID = 1;
UPDATE student SET email = 'Albert@gmail.com.com' WHERE SID = 1;
UPDATE student SET email = 'Sam@gmail.com' WHERE SID = 1;
UPDATE student SET email = 'Tom@gmail.com' WHERE SID = 1;
UPDATE student SET email = 'Liz@gmail.com' WHERE SID = 1;
```

But if the new data is same for all the records then you can use the following way.

```
UPDATE student
SET email = 'bob'@gmail.com
WHERE SID IN ('S01', 'S02', 'S03', 'S04', 'S05');
```

This is valid only if the same value is being updated.

Answer (score 1):

You Need to use `update` statement <del>query</del> instead of insert again .
try below query for every email use student id for where clause.

```
UPDATE student set email='Bob@gmail.com' where SID='S021';
```

Comment: student_id should be SID.

Comment: yes correct I just added it in example you can put SID , Now edited and changed to SID

Comment: I need to add data into multiple rows. Do you any suggestions for it ?

Comment: if you have to add data in multiple columns use below query

Comment: I have 6 columns

Comment: UPDATE student set email='Bob@gmail.com',student_name="xyz"  where SID='S021';

Comment: like above query you can  add your 6 columns with comma separated values

Comment: Sorry I need to add data for 6 rows  in a single column using a single quary

Comment: use below query you need to insert SID there for every one

Comment: UPDATE student set email='Bob@gmail.com' where student_id='S021';
 UPDATE student set email='John@gmail.com' where student_id='';
 UPDATE student set email='Albert@gmail.com' where student_id='';
 UPDATE student set email='Sam@gmail.com' where student_id='';
 UPDATE student set email='Tom@gmail.com' where student_id='';
 UPDATE student set email='Liz@gmail.com' where student_id='';